# How to get sales amount measure appear either red or green in MDX cube?

Tags: colors, mdx, cube, measure

I am new to mdx, this is a simple task yet, am not able to get it right. I have a Sales measure group with sales amount, tax, order quantity etc.

I am  trying to get the sales amount appear either green or red if sales amount> 50 then red else..whatever color preferred. 
Thanks

Comment: Which MDX client / tool are you using ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the [FORE_COLOR](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145573.aspx) cell property.

Here is an example with a calculated member:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[color] AS [Measures].[sales amount],
             FORE_COLOR = IIf([Measures].[sales amount] > 50, 255, 65280)
```